# How to add a reference to a library

Tags: c#, dll

I have found a math parser [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274093/Math-Parser-NET). I have never added something like this to a program and was wondering what I need to do to add thing like this to a program. For example I want to know where to put the file and how to call it in the headers so that I can use the classes inside the file. I looking for general instructions that can be applied to other things as well.

Comment: are you trying to add this to a C project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have come from a bit of a C background. C# is a little different in the way that we pull in external code, and its actually quite a bit easier than C.

To reference some code using Visual Studio, you will need to add a reference to that dll. once you have the dll included (via a reference) in your project you can use it in your code by adding a using statement and then instantiating objects from that library

MSDN docs around this are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

EDIT:
if you are outside of VS as you have specified there's a few things you will need to do:

- Let your compiler know where the assembly is so that it can correctly link
- Add the assembly to your running directory (it should sit alongside your executable)

  - OR add your library to the GAC
  - OR manually load it with an Assembly.Load call

Comment: Sorry. I don't use visual C#. I use notepad++. Is there a work around to the referencing of the .dll file.

Comment: @JustinRolf what are you using to compile your application?

Comment: I have the Microsoft .NET framework installed so I just use a command in CMD.

Comment: I suggest you get Visual Studio Express Edition (which is free)

Comment: @JustinRolf are you using CSC?

Comment: if you are usign CSC i think you can use the AdditionalLibPaths parameter see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5c8athz.aspx

Comment: Sorry for asking for a work around. I took a C# class awhile ago and just remembered that it takes a command in the command prompt to reference files so thank you for going the extra length to find the info, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Please don't post old MSDN links. I corrected your link to remove the version-specific part.